# Why sorting of records in table is not as per clustered index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, primary-key, clustered-index

I have been preparing for interview and just come to these thing.

I have executed following statements:

```
create table trial
(
    Id int not null,
    Name varchar(10)
)

alter table trial add constraint unq unique clustered (Name)

alter table trial add constraint pk primary key nonclustered(Id)

insert into trial values (1,'a'),(3,'d'),(5,'b'),(2,'c')

select * from trial
```

Result is as shown here:

[image]

My question is: Why result is not sorted as per name column as name column has clustered index?

Result is:

```
1 a
2 c
3 d
5 b
```

How to use index for physical sorting of table?

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (Indexes are always more or less product specific.)

Comment: MS sql 2014 developer edition

Comment: Read this article on the topic. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case I am sure optimizer decided to do a full table scan or nonclustered index scan, since it is very small. You can include actual execution plan and see this:

[image]

You can force to use clustered index:

```
SELECT * FROM TRIAL WITH (INDEX(UNQ))
```

And you will probably get:

[image]

and result set:

```
Id  Name
1   a
5   b
2   c
3   d
```

But you should not really do this, because ordering is still not guarantied. If you want your results to be sorted by some columns, do it explicitly!

I will copy a fragment from the book `Exam 70-461: Querying Microsoft SQL Server 2012` where you can get some good explanation:

> It might seem like the output is sorted by empid, but that’s not
>   guaranteed. What could be more confusing is that if you run the query
>   repeatedly, it seems like the result keeps being returned in the same
>   order; but again, that’s not guaranteed. When the database engine (SQL
>   Server in this case) processes this query, it knows that it can return
>   the data in any order because there is no explicit instruction to
>   return the data in a specific order. It could be that, due to
>   optimization and other reasons, the SQL Server database engine chose
>   to process the data in a particular way this time. There’s even some
>   likelihood that such choices will be repeated if the physical
>   circumstances remain the same. But there’s a big difference between
>   what’s likely to happen due to optimization and other reasons and
>   what’s actually guaranteed.
>
> The database engine may—and sometimes
>   does—change choices that can affect the order in which rows are
>   returned, knowing that it is free to do so. Examples for such changes
>   in choices include changes in data distribution, availability of
>   physical structures such as indexes, and availability of resources
>   like CPUs and memory. Also, with changes in the engine after an
>   upgrade to a newer version of the product, or even after application
>   of a service pack, optimization aspects may change. In turn, such
>   changes could affect, among other things, the order of the rows in the
>   result.
>
> In short, this cannot be stressed enough: **A query that doesn’t**
>   **have an explicit instruction to return the rows in a particular order**
>   **doesn’t guarantee the order of rows in the result**. When you do need
>   such a guarantee, the only way to provide it is by adding an ORDER BY
>   clause to the query, and that’s the focus of the next section.

EDIT based on comments:

The thing is that even if you use clustered index it may return unordered set. Suppose you have physical order of clustered keys like `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`. Most of the time you will get `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` but there can be situations when optimizer decides to do **parallel reads** and say it has 2 parallel reads and it reads `(1, 2, 3)` and `(4, 5)`. Now it may happen that `(4, 5)` will be returned first and then `(1, 2, 3)` can be returned. If you have no `order by` clause engine will not spend its resources ordering that set and will give you `(4, 5, 1, 2, 3)`. So this explains why you should always ensure you have `order by` clause when you want ordering.

Comment: Thanks.. for this clarification. Actually what I knew is physical ordering of records in table is always as per clustered index. .. But I was wrong...

Comment: @Sagar, no you were correct in that. I will explain in more details in the answer.

Comment: thanx.. I am really satisfied with that answer. Parallel reads ... correct.

Answer (score 4):

Repeat:  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  SQL result sets are *unordered*, unless the query includes an `order by` clause.

So, if you want data in order, then use an `order by`:

```
select t.*
from trial t
order by t.name;
```

If you want results in a particular order, use `order by`.  SQL Server has a good optimizer.  If it can use an index for the query -- to avoid an actual sort -- then it usually will use the index.

Comment: yes that i know.. why records in table are not sorted as per clustered index??

Comment: Sorry, you have no way to know how records are sorted in table. You can only see, how records are returned to you when you query them - and this is purely SQL internal undetermined thing, unless you request specified order.

Comment: @Sager . . . The issue is not how tables are sorted.  The issue is how the query works.  If you did a data dump of the pages, you would probably find that the data is, indeed, ordered on the data pages.  However, the query doesn't have to respect that.